# Sphinx is there a way to insert into distributed index

Tags: sphinx

i.e

```
index main {
        type = distributed
        local = rt
        agent = 10.0.0.2:3312:rt
        agent = 10.0.0.3:3312:rt
        agent = 10.0.0.4:3312:rt
        agent_connect_timeout = 200
        agent_query_timeout = 1000
}
```

Is there a way to insert into distributed index

Answer (score 1):

Not right now.

The main thing Sphinx doesn't really have a concept to know which agent(s) the insert would be propagated to. You probably have a custom sharding idea, which sphinx doesn't know about.

For now the application would have to know how to connect to the agent(s) directly, and run the insert into the true index.